# How to display usage of the Intel HD 3000?

Tags: intel-graphics

I can see the CPU usage with `top` and `htop`. Is there some way to monitor the usage of the Intel HD 3000 graphics card in my system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tool called intel-gpu-tools from the http://intellinuxgraphics.org/ project, which provides the command intel_gpu_top.

found via: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38568/26851